# What does the ^ symbol mean (specifically, within error_reporting)

Tags: php, error-handling

these two statements:

```
    $old = errorreport(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_STRICT);
    $old = errorreport(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
```

Seem to do the same thing.  What is the meaning of "^",  "~"  ?  I cant find a reference for these symbols.

Comment: I believe this question should be re-opened, it takes more than the information on the linked question to understand how bit operators relate to E_ALL and E_NOTICE constants. I believe a proper answer should include why and how bit operators effect error reporting behavior in php.

Comment: i would say the first link on the dupe to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php covers it

Comment: @Dagon - Fair enough, I did not see that link when I first visited the question. That link answers the question perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` means "except" [DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

In your second example that would mean `E_ALL` except `E_NOTICE` and `E_STRICT`

The `^` is a "flipper":

> ^ is the xor (bit flipping) operator and would actually turn notices *on* if they were previously off (in the error level on its left).

Comment: Ok, so in #2, we are saying e_all, which turns on notice and strict, but then, we are flipping those two, to turn them off. (?)  I wonder if the two examples are functionally identical?

Comment: It would seem to me, sans any testing, they are functionally identical.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). At this page you could have some examples of using them to make error reporting settings.